# Trouble with Polymorphism example from Programming in Objective-C, Stephen Kochan, 6th Edition (Program 9.1)

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

** UPDATE **
I have changed the extraneous division by zero error in the reduce method.  This was not causing the problem.

*Original Question Text*
I am in the process of reading Stephen Kochan's book, Programming in Objective-C, 6th Edition.  There is a program in Capter 9 (9.1) that demonstrates Polymorphism by having complex numbers and fraction each have a ***print*** method and an ***add*** method.

```
resultComplex = [c1 add: c2]
```

and

```
resultFraction = [f1 add: f2]
```

and likewise with the print methods.  It is completely understandable to me but there appears to be a bust somewhere in the code and I was hoping someone could help.  The book is excellent and previous chapters build on themselves with existing code.  The earlier versions of the code have all worked.  I am suspecting that I have done something stupid like mis-typed something but I've been pouring over it for a few hours.

The **output** is as follows:

```
Chapter_9[5617:303]  18 + 2.5i 
Chapter_9[5617:303]          +
Chapter_9[5617:303]  -5 + 3.2i 
Chapter_9[5617:303] -----------
Chapter_9[5617:303]  13 + 5.7i 
Chapter_9[5617:303] 
Chapter_9[5617:303] 1/10
Chapter_9[5617:303]    +
Chapter_9[5617:303] 2/15
Chapter_9[5617:303] ------

(lldb)
```

The program is able to add the Complex numbers but dies at the point it is required to add the Fractions.  Xcode identifies ***add*** method in Fraction as the offender the following line as the offensive point:

```
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];  // must be alloc/init here
```

I will include the class files (.h and .m) for the Fraction class.  I am leaving out the Complex class because that part of the code runs fine, although there is an analogous line in that Class that seems to work fine.  If it is necessary, I will update the post to add those.  I just didn't want to drown everyone with that code if my error is obvious.

**UPDATE**
I am inserting a picture of the debug and output

[image]

**Fraction Header File**

```
//
//  Fraction.h
//  Chapter_9

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void)         print;
-(void)         setTo: (int) n over: (int)d;
-(double)       convertToNum;
-(Fraction *)   add: (Fraction *) f;
-(void)         reduce;

@end
```

**Fraction Implementation File**

```
//
//  Fraction.m
//  Chapter_9


#import "Fraction.h"

@implementation Fraction

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(double) convertToNum
    {
        if (denominator != 0)
            return (double) numerator / denominator;
        else
        return NAN;
    }

    -(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d
    {
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}

-(void) reduce
{
    int u = numerator;
    int v= denominator;
    int temp;

    while (v!= 0) {
        temp = u % v;
        u = v;
        v = temp;

    numerator /= u;
    denominator /=u;  //originally there was an unrelated error here
    }
}


-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{
    // To add two fractions:
    // a/b + c/d = ((a*d) + (b*c) / (b*d)
    // Store the answer in a new Fraction object called (result)
// ************* Here is where Xcode identifies the error *******************
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];  // must be alloc/init here


    result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;


    result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;

    [result reduce];

    return result;
}

@end
```

**Program Main File:**

```
//
//  main.m
//  Chapter_9

// Programming in Objective-C, Stephen Kochan, 6th Edition
//Problem 9.1: Shared Method Names: Polymorphism


#import "Fraction.h"
#import "Complex.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Fraction *f1 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
        Fraction *f2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
        Fraction *fracResult;

        Complex *c1 = [[Complex alloc] init];
        Complex *c2 = [[Complex alloc] init];
        Complex *compResult;

        [f1 setTo: 1 over: 10];
        [f2 setTo: 2 over: 15];


        [c1 setReal: 18 andImaginary:2.5];
        [c2 setReal: -5 andImaginary: 3.2];

        //add and print 2 complex numbers

        [c1 print]; NSLog(@"         +"); [c2 print];
        NSLog(@"-----------");
        compResult = [c1 add: c2];  //compResult is alloc/init in add method
        [compResult print];
        NSLog(@"\n");

        // add and print 2 fractions
        [f1 print]; NSLog(@"   +"); [f2 print];
        NSLog(@"------");

        //  ******************** Here is where the method call takes place that causes the error

        fracResult = [f1 add: f2]; //fracResult is alloc/init in add method
        [fracResult print];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am obviously new to Xcode and Objective-C and so am not able to debug on my own.  Sorry for the long and drawn out explanation.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode should be giving you a fairly clear division-by-zero error in your `reduce` method. You haven't copied it correctly from the book, I'm guessing, because your division-by-zero error is being caused by an error in your GCD algorithm.

This:

```
while (v!= 0) {
    temp = u % v;
    u = v;
    v = temp;

    numerator /= u;
    denominator /=v;
}
```

should be this:

```
while (v!= 0) {
    temp = u % v;
    u = v;
    v = temp;
}
numerator /= u;
denominator /=u;
```

Comment: You are correct about the error in the reduce method, but that is not the cause of the problem.  I have fixed it and the problem persists.  Thanks though!

Comment: It is the cause of the problem, works fine when I make the change based on the code you posted. Post the changed code at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't mean to be stubborn.  When I changed the v to a u in the reduce method, I re-ran the program and it still produced the error.  I have since re-written the Fraction.m file from scratch and it works.  My apologies!

Comment: Changing `v` to `u` wasn't the only change you needed, you had to move the closing brace, too.

Comment: Thank you.  Quite right.  well, at least I got the Polymorphism!!

Comment: Actually, to add to your woes, this code really doesn't have anything to do with polymorphism. Maybe it just serves as a base for a later example in that chapter, but right now it's a little mystifying why that term is being used in respect of it.